# Finding the implicit value for Json in play

Tags: scala, playframework, implicit-conversion

When I use the following code:

```
import JsonImpl.graphFormat
val js = Json.toJson(g)(graphFormat)
```

My code compiles and works fine but when I do this it doesn't work and says: "No Json serializer found for type SGraph. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type."

```
import JsonImpl.graphFormat
val js = Json.toJson(g)
```

`JsonImpl` is:

```
object JsonImpl{
    implicit val graphFormat = Json.format[SGraph]
}
```

I don't want to use companion object for my `SGraph` class. What is the problem and why it cannot find the implicit value?

Comment: Either should work, so there's something else in your code that's causing problems. Can you try adding an explicit return type to the instance definition, and then maybe `-Xlog-implicits`?

Comment: @TravisBrown
`Typing graphFormat solved it, thanks!
I guess learning Scala type system is out of my abilities. there is always something!

Comment: Providing explicit type annotations for type class instances is always a good idea (it ought to be mandatory), especially when you're dealing with macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of completeness: `Json.format` is a macro, and when you're dealing with macros it's a good idea to make sure what you're getting back is appropriately statically typed:

```
object JsonImpl{
  implicit val graphFormat: Format[SGraph] = Json.format[SGraph]
}
```

In fact this is a good idea whenever you're dealing with implicit values, and it'll save you a lot of confusion (sometimes because you've done something wrong, and sometimes because the compiler has).